# STS-3.6.4-RELEASE tcserver not configured after tcruntime-instance.sh

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

I recently installed STS-3.5.4-RELEASE and used the tcruntime-instance.sh script to define a new server.  I was able to successfully create a new server in STS using the "New" menu item and selecting the "existing instance" option pointing to the server I created using the tcruntime-instance.sh script.  However, when I attempt to run the new server, it fails with the error message:

```
Apr 01, 2015 1:08:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (23, 68) : org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
Apr 01, 2015 1:08:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (23, 68) : org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener
Apr 01, 2015 1:08:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

Any suggestions of how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated, since using the tcruntime-instance.sh script worked to create new servers prior to upgrading to the STS.3.6.4-RELEASE version.

Answer (score 0):

When you created a server tc Server instance from command line using tcruntime-instance.sh script without specifying the tomcat version it would create a tc server instance based on Tomcat 7 by default. The STS default tc server runtime is based on Tomcat 8 for managing tc server instances based on Tomcat 8.
Therefore, you've created a Tomcat 7 based instance and tried to run it with a Tomcat 8 based runtime and got an error. Errors are possible in this case since configurations might be conflicting. The wizard for creating a tc Server instance in STS has a warning displayed on the page you browse to the existing instance if selected runtime Tomcat version is mismatched with the existing instance Tomcat version.
There are 2 alternative solutions to fix this:

1. Create a tomcat 8 based instance with tcruntime-instance.sh
   script by using "-v 8.0.20.B.RELEASE", e.g. `/tcruntime-instance.sh
   create fromCLI_80 -t base -v 8.0.20.B.RELEASE` Then creating a
   server from this instance would work with STS default runtime.
2. Create a tomcat 7 based tc server 3.1 runtime in STS via Preferences
   -> Server -> Runtime Environments. Click Add button, select Pivotal tc Server 3.0-3.1, on the next page point to your tc server installation folder and don't forget to select Tomcat 7.x server version on the bottom drop-down. Create the runtime. Now pick that runtime on the bottom on the first page of the server creation wizard if you want to use tomcat 7 based existing instance